# SQL Server connection established during design, but not during runtime

Tags: entity-framework-6, amazon-rds

I have created an Amazon RDS DB instance. I can connect to it and perform operations with SSMS. I can also bind to it using Entity Framework DB-first and generate my model. However, when I run my app, using the same connection string that was generated in the data access project, I get a "the network path was not found" error while trying to establish a connection to the DB.

Let me be clear: the db exists, the right ports are open, and the connection string is correct. I am the only one connecting to the database and the status is "available".

So what's going on? Has anyone experienced something like this?

Let me also further mention that I have already checked the usual things like internet connectivity, firewall rules, state of the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

well it started working all of a sudden. So I guess this problem will only pop up again in production or something.